# How to get only specific tags of elementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="dates">
  <span class="dates>value</span>
</div>
```

I'd like to extract all elements with class `dates`, but only the span elements.

How would I have to modify the following JS:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dates"); //gets both div + span
```

Finally I'd like to extract all text values of the span tags.

I'm using the "old" `getElementsByClassName` to also support older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("span.dates");
```

Otherwise, you can use [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) to filter down your existing elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dates");
for(var i=elements.length; i--;) {
    if(elements[i].tagName.toLowerCase() != "span") continue;
    // Do work
}
```

Comment: Tagname is guaranteed to be uppercase, so a simple comparison with SPAN will work fine.

Comment: @torazaburo Not true, in XHTML `tagName` preserves case

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you may use the CSS selector with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.dates, span.dates');
```

It is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility) by the following browsers:

- Chrome - 1
- Firefox (Gecko) - 3.5 (1.9.1)
- Internet Explorer - 9 and 8 (CSS2 selectors only)
- Opera - 10
- Safari (WebKit) - 3.2 (525.3)

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer to also support some older browsers.

Comment: @membersound Keep in mind that `getElementsByClassName` is also not supported by old IEs.